# Reference for Quantum field theory in $S^1 \times R$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I am looking for a reference where it is considered QFT on a space given in a circle, plus a time coordinate, namely QFT in $S^1\times R$.

Comment: I studied $S^1 \times R$ in Birrell and Davies. The calculated expectation value of $T\mu \nu$. Yeah that's it by 2 different methods.

Answer (score 2):

Quantum field theory on a cylinder? I think you are talking about conformal field theory in two dimensions. You can learn almost everything about this huge field from the book [Conformal Field Theory](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387947853) by Philippe Francesco. [Conformal field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_field_theory) is a quantum field theory that has conformal invariance.

If you are interested in quantum field theories that has the ordinary Poincare symmetry, then you may be interested in [integrable models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrable_models) in two dimensions, such as [Sine-Gordon model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine-Gordon_equation) and Sinh-Gordon model in two dimensions. These theories are called integrable because they have an infinite number of conserved charges. You can find detailed introductions from [Statistical Field Theory: An Introduction to Exactly Solved Models in Statistical Physics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199547580) by Giuseppe Mussardo.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out basically any introductions to string theory. QFT on $S^1 \times R$ is exactly what you study when looking at closed strings.

Ibanez and Uranga have published a Text book that I liked - you could also start by checking out these lecture notes:
https://www.thphys.uni-heidelberg.de/~weigand/Skript-strings11-12/Strings.pdf

Comment: The string worldsheet is described by *conformal* field theory on $S^1 \times R$. OP didn't mention anything about conformal symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness I mention an alternative approach to quantum field theories on a cylinder ($S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$). They can be equivalently formulated as worldline theories.

Let us consider a generic scalar field theory

$$ S=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int d^2\sigma \sqrt{g}\, g^{ab}\left( \partial_a\phi\partial_b\phi+4\pi V(\phi) \right) $$

If we put the theory on a cylinder of radius $r$ by choosing $\sigma_1\in[0,2\pi r], \sigma_2\equiv\tau\in[0,1]$, by fixing the metric to

$$
g_{ab}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & T^2
    \end{pmatrix},
$$

and by expanding $X$ as

$$
 X(\sigma_1,\sigma_2)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}X_n(\sigma_2)e^{ \frac{i n\sigma_1}{r}},
$$

then we obtain, in the low energy regime, a worldline theory of particles  described by the action

$$
S(X_0,X_n)=\int_0^1 d\tau\, \left(\frac{r}{2T}\dot{X}_0+V(X_0)\right)+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\int_0^1d\tau\, \left\{\frac{r}{T}|\dot{X_n}|^2+m_n^2|X_n|^2\right\}
$$

These worldline theories have some universal features, independent of the form of the potential.
More details can be found in this [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/JHEP10(2022)110):
Dogaru, A.I., Delgado, R.C. C*ylinder quantum field theories at small coupling.* J. High Energ. Phys. 2022, 110 (2022)